# Can't set the width of links to be the same

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a horizontal navigation menu with button style links but I can't manage to get them all to be the same width. I've had no luck using "width: px" as it doesn't seem to work with links. Any suggestions?

Thanks

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
   <script type = "text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
   <title></title>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="main">

      <div class="header">
         <img src="images/logo.jpg" />
      </div>

      <div class="navigation"><ul id = "linkbar">
         <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Links</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Guestbook</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Contact</a></li></ul>
      </div>

   <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, 

feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae 

est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum</a>

   </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
   background-color: lightgray;

   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;

}

.header {
   background-color:white;
} 

.header img {
   vertical-align: top;
}

.main {
   background-color: limegreen;
   text-align: center;
   width: 900px;
   margin: auto;
}
   a:link {color:white; text-decoration:none;}      /* unvisited link */
   a:visited {color:white; text-decoration:none;}  /* visited link */
   a:hover {color:red; text-decoration:underline;}  /* mouse over link*/
   a:active {color:red; text-decoration:underline;}  /* selected link */

.navigation {
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #f8901f; 
   /*background-image:url('images/navbar.jpg');*/
}

#linkbar a {  
              padding: 14px 0px 13px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    border: none;
}

#linkbar {
   margin-top: 0;
}

#linkbar li {
  padding: 11px 0px 10px 0px; 
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  line-height: 2.5em;
}

#linkbar a:hover, #linkbar .current_page_item a {
    background: url(images/img05.gif) repeat-x left top;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: You could make the links `inline-block`s: `display: inline-block;` (works in IE >= 8).

Comment: @Rudie - Can't we forget about IE pre-IE9? :S :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because A tags are `display: inline` by default, and thus cannot take a width.

See the last two lines:

```
#linkbar a {  
    padding: 14px 0px 13px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3gwfY/

Answer (score 1):

Set the width:..px property on the <li> elements, not on the <a> elements.

Answer (score 1):

Links are `inline` elements. They can't have a set width, which is why your code wasn't working.

Try making them `inline-block`:

```
.navigation a {
  display: inline-block
}
```

But, personally, I'd style the `<li>` tags instead of the links. I just don't feel right when I fiddle with `<a>` tags like that...

Comment: I agree, the LI tags are better to style, unless the OP wants the entire width to act as a link, in which case the A tag would need to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `<a>` elements (links) are inline elements, which will not accept width values. Use `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/TXSkr/